# Create prime face radio button from list of complex object

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, selectoneradio

I am trying to built a web page using prime-faces.I want to implement a page for a quiz. My bean has list of Question DTO which contains list of Answer DTO and I want to show the answers of each question with radio button because user can choose only one answer and one question could have only one correct answer at most. I have total 4 questions. I have written a following code

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="parkingOptions" value="#{theBean.userAnswer}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{quizQuestionDto.quizAnswerList.answer}"/>
                            </h:selectOneRadio>
```

My bean has method called getUserAnswer and setUserAnswer to store an answer of  user choice which accepts String . I an confused whether it should accept string or list of string because I have more than 1 Question to ask.
I am getting an exception

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "answer"   at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)  at
>   javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:163)   at
>   javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:51)  at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)    at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:129)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.initializeItems(SelectItemsIterator.java:208)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.hasNext(SelectItemsIterator.java:135)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer.java:133)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.component.RepeatRenderer.encodeChildren(RepeatRenderer.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:621)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:1110)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    ... 61 more

Comment: QuizQuestionDto has a list of Objects of QuizAnswerDto and QuizAnswerDto has a property called answer.

Comment: quizanswerlist is a list of objects of quizanswerDTO which has more than one property but I want to show one property called answer. How could I show that on UI?